# SQL to Linq statement

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

I've got this SQL statement that I'm trying to convert to linq:

```
SELECT i.*
FROM Issues i
WHERE IssueID IN (SELECT ChildIssueId
                    FROM LinkedIssues
                    WHERE IssueId = 28438)
OR IssueID IN (SELECT IssueId
                FROM LinkedIssues
                WHERE ChildIssueId = 28438)
```

Here's what the data in the table looks like:

[image: Table Data]

So in the sql above, I get issues 19220, 28436, & 28440 back.  Here's what I've tried with no luck:

```
var childIssues = (from i in Issues
                 join li in LinkedIssues
                      on i.IssueID equals li.IssueId
                 where (from li2 in LinkedIssues
                        where li.IssueId == 28438 || li.ChildIssueId == 28438
                        select li2).Contains(28438)
                 select new LinkedIssuesModel()
                 {
                     IssueID = li.ChildIssueId,
                     CustomerName = i.Room.Location.Customer.CustomerName,
                     LocationName = i.Room.Location.LocationName,
                     ReceivedDate = i.ReceivedDate,
                     IssueSummary = i.IssueSummary,
                     IssueDescription = i.IssueDescription
                 }).ToList();
```

I need to know how to convert SQL IN statements to linq.  I have [LinqPad](https://www.linqpad.net/) but it doesn't convert it when I click the lambda button.  I've also downloaded and tried [Linqer](http://www.sqltolinq.com/downloads) but it throws an "Object not set to an instance Object" error.

Comment: Use one or more LEFT JOINs instead of the IN construct, i.e. `SELECT i.* FROM Issues i LEFT JOIN LinkedIssues li ON li.ChildIssueID = i.IssueID AND li.IssueId = 28438 LEFT JOIN LinkedIssues li2 ON li2.IssueID = i.IssueID AND li.ChildIssueId = 28438 WHERE li.issueID IS NOT NULL or li2.IssueID IS NOT NULL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following:

```
    var childIssues = (from i in Issues
                 from li in LinkedIssues
                 where (li.IssueId == 28438 && li.ChildIssueId == i.IssueID) 
                    || (li.ChildIssueId == 28438 && li.IssueId == i.IssueID)
                 select new LinkedIssuesModel()
                 {
                     IssueID = li.ChildIssueId,
                     CustomerName = i.Room.Location.Customer.CustomerName,
                     LocationName = i.Room.Location.LocationName,
                     ReceivedDate = i.ReceivedDate,
                     IssueSummary = i.IssueSummary,
                     IssueDescription = i.IssueDescription
                 }).ToList();
```

EDIT: Fixed query to address `li.ChildIssueId` on the `select`.

Comment: I was about to ask why not use joins in the original question's comments when this popped up. A JOIN is easier than an IN, and frequently faster.

Comment: @LaughingVergil I think contains is faster because if can short-circuit

Comment: @Hogan - that may be true sometimes, but I had to deal with programmers doing IN on upwards of 10k individual discrete values. It isn't faster then - at least not up through SQL 2008 R2 (I didn't have time to test SQL 2012 before I left that job).

Comment: Is `(x || y) && (a || b)` the same as `(x && a) || (y && b)`?

Comment: @LaughingVergil -- I agree with you IN is always slower than JOIN on an SQL platform.  This is Linq.  It works different.

Comment: (The answer to my question is "no" so this is not the same logic as the original question.)

Comment: @wdosanjos -- yeah -- that looks good -- wouldn't just select `i` work to be the same as the SQL?

Comment: @wdosanjos - Thank you for your solution, it works great.  I did have a question though; how can I get the field values from `LinkedIssues`?  I have a few properties on the `LinkedIssuesModel` that come from that table (notes, CreatedBy, DateCreated).

Comment: @Robert I fixed the query to address the issue with LinkedIssues properties.

Answer (score 0):

You are not joining.

```
var childIssues = Issues.
                    Where(x => LinkedIssues.
                                 Where(z => z.IssueId = 28438).
                                 Select(z => z.ChildIssueId).
                                 Contains(x.IssueID) 
                             ||
                               LinkedIssues.
                                 Where(z => z.ChildIssueId = 28438).
                                 Select(z => z.IssueId).
                                 Contains(x.IssueID) 
                    );
```